# PHP json_decode error: Array value found, but an object is required

Tags: php, arrays, json, jsonschema

I am trying to decode following JSON file

```
{
     "email": "mail@gmail.com",
     "password": "12345",
     "languageProficiency": {
            "language": "English",
             "proficiency": 4
   },
     "tags": [
         {
            "name": "singing"
         },
         {
           "name": "dance"
         }
   ]
}
```

When I do this

```
 $data = json_decode($jsonContent, true);
 echo $data;
 die();
```

I have following error:

*Array value found, but an object is required*

**Question**

1) How can I view data from JSON
2) How can I access property of each object in *tags* array

I am validating Json content againsts this schema

```
  {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "password": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "languageProficiency": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "language": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "proficiency": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "language",
          "proficiency"
        ]
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "name"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "email",
      "password",
      "languageProficiency",
      "tags"
    ]
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I tried following to view json content

```
 print_r($data)
```

But I still get same error

Comment: You can't `echo` an array as far as I know.

Comment: For this code you'll get "Notice: Array to string conversion". So your error comes from other place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$data = json_decode($jsonContent, true);`

Above line of code will return Array, for which you can not use echo directly to print an array.

To print specific value of an array (e.g. email), do it like this:

```
echo $data["email"];
```

---

**Tip:**

Use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to know the array structure like this,

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try print_r($data) to explore values